# Create IIS asp.net 4.0 web application using powershell

Tags: powershell, iis

I am trying to create a web application using power shell (Not DSC).

The script creates the web application successfully, however, in IIS when right click on the app>Manage>Browse, it tries to navigate to http://y:81. The correct address should be http://localhost:81/. Where is the mistake in the script below?

Also, what are the steps to convert this script to DSC?

Please help to know where am I going wrong.

Below is the script:

```
Import-Module WebAdministration
$iisAppPoolName = "YAppPool"
$iisAppPoolDotNetVersion = "v4.0"
$iisAppName = "Y"
$directoryPath = "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Y"

#navigate to the app pools root
cd IIS:\AppPools\

#check if the app pool exists
if (!(Test-Path $iisAppPoolName -pathType container))
{
    #create the app pool
    $appPool = New-Item $iisAppPoolName
    $appPool | Set-ItemProperty -Name "managedRuntimeVersion" -Value $iisAppPoolDotNetVersion
}

#navigate to the sites root
cd IIS:\Sites\

#check if the site exists
if (Test-Path $iisAppName -pathType container)
{
    return
}

#create the site
$iisApp = New-Item $iisAppName -bindings @{protocol="http";bindingInformation=":81:" + $iisAppName} -physicalPath $directoryPath
$iisApp | Set-ItemProperty -Name "applicationPool" -Value $iisAppPoolName
Out-Null

cd C:\inetpub\wwwroot
md .\Y


$Acl = Get-Acl "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Y"

$Ar = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule("NETWORK SERVICE", "FullControl", "ContainerInherit,ObjectInherit", "None", "allow")

$Acl.SetAccessRule($Ar)
Set-Acl "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Y" $Acl
-wait
```

Comment: What is the question here? How to edit AppPool settings? Or the binding? Or how to create a DSC config based on the above? Make up your mind please

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen Thanks! I just got drifted while drafting the questions.